# Vf page Issue with account lookup

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

I am not able to get account name as lookup to account as it is standard lookup field it appear as read only.

As `<apex:inputfield value="{!quote.accountid}">` should get that .

[image]

```
>  <apex:page standardController="quote" >
>               
> 
> >   <apex:form >
> >                 <apex:pageBlock >
> >                 <apex:pageblockSection title="Quote Information" columns="2">
> >                 <apex:inputField value="{!quote.Name}"/>
> >                 <apex:inputField value="{!quote.ExpirationDate}"/>                
> >                 <apex:inputField value="{!quote.OpportunityId}"/>
> >                 <apex:inputField value="{!quote.IsSyncing}"/>
> >                 <apex:inputField value="{!quote.ACCOUNTId}"/>
> >                 <apex:inputField value="{!quote.Status}"/>
> >                 
> >                 <apex:inputField value="{!quote.Description}"/>
> >                
> >         
> >                 </apex:pageblockSection>   
> >                 </apex:pageBlock>         
> >                 </apex:form>
> >                 </apex:page>
```

Comment: Check that you have permission for that field or not

Comment: I cannot change permission by default it is read only

Comment: If it is readonly then why are you trying to edit that fields using vf page. Using input means that you want to edit that value. So, visualforce won't show input.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Standard Controller which honors field level security.

You can use a custom controller which executes in system mode, where the field and object permissions are ignored, unless specified explicitly.